# Convert array of objects in javascript to a desired array based on key children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

The following is the original array that I want to convert, its structure is the same as columns of andt

```
const base = [
  {
    name: "Jonh"
  },
  {
    name: "jane"
  },
  {
    name: "Tom",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Jery"
      },
      {
        name: "Mart"
      },
      {
        name: "Mary",
        children: [
          {
            name: "bob"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "boboy"
  }
]
```

And this is the array I want to convert into
My simple wish is to bring children out to the same level as its parent array and still keep its parent intact

```
const result = [
  {
    name: "Jonh"
  },
  {
    name: "jane"
  },
  {
    name: "Tom",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Jery"
      },
      {
        name: "Mart"
      },
      {
        name: "Mary",
        children: [
          {
            name: "bob"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  [
    {
      name: "Jery"
    },
    {
      name: "Mart"
    },
    {
      name: "Mary",
      children: [
        {
          name: "bob"
        }
      ]
    },
    [
      {
        name: "bob"
      }
    ],
  ],
  {
    name: "boboy"
  }
]
```

For some people it's easy but I'm new and hope everyone can help

Here's what I tried

```
const filterChild = (listColumn: IColumns[]): any[] => {
    return listColumn.map((col) => {
      return col.children ? filterChild(col.children) : col;
    });
  };
```

The purpose of this action is that I am trying to create a custom table with the "Grouping table head" function like andt's.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you want to do is add children and "grand children" etc. etc. recursively to the top level of the array of objects? Just want to make sure before I post an answer. Thanks

Comment: just as you think

Comment: Alright, with that in mind, should we take into account the fact that names may or may not be unique... Or are we guaranteed that they are unique? If we are unsure if they are unique how should we handle conflicts?

Comment: There is a bit of confusion in my question
The result I want should be

Comment: You can review the array I want "result"

Comment: My simple wish is to bring children out to the same level as its parent array and still keep its parent intact

Comment: Alright I've added a code snippet to bring those children out to the **same level** as the parent array elements. I hope my answer helps. I've tried to answer your real problem and have also included a second way of doing the function which will give the output you have in your question, but is adding array of arrays to your object. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that can be easily handled by recursion. Here is one such example of using recursion (and a helper function) to achieve this very task.

```
const bringOutChildren = (arr) => {
    let result = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        result.push(arr[i]);
        if(result[i].children){//will only run when children is defined.
            result = result.concat(bringOutChildren(result[i].children)); 
            //If there are children then we will concatenate the deeper structure.
        }
    }
    return result;
}
const base = [
  {
    name: "Jonh"
  },
  {
    name: "jane"
  },
  {
    name: "Tom",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Jery"
      },
      {
        name: "Mart"
      },
      {
        name: "Mary",
        children: [
          {
            name: "bob"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "boboy"
  }
]
const result = bringOutChildren(base); // result will be what you have asked for.
```

Note that I'm using an arrow syntax function here... But you could have just as easily defined the function like `function bringOutChildren(arr){` ... to do the exact same thing. You can read about recursion [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-recursion-in-javascript/) . If you would like to read up about the javascript array concatenation you can read up about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

### EDIT

Because @Robby Cornelisson's comments, I have decided to show a function that will give the exact output the SO author originally had (in case it wasn't a mistake)... In which case we change one line of code in the "bringOutChildren" function.

```
function bringOutChildren(arr){
    let result = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        result.push(arr[i]);
        if(result[i].children){//will only run when children is defined.
            result = result.concat([bringOutChildren(result[i].children)]);
            //Notice that the concatenation is now wraped in [] which will append an array.
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

You can use this function in the same way the original was.

Comment: Doesn't produce the requested output.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen It does what the author wants, I would edit his question but the queue is full... And his requested output has the wrong format as is... Sorry, I just followed what he said in the further comments.

Comment: The requested output is perfectly valid. Your solution produces an array with 8 elements. The requested output only has 5.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I perfectly understand that, but the SO author made it clear that he simply wants to bring the children to the top level.. He doesn't want to add arrays of arrays to his array of objects... To be clear though... changing one line of code in this example would give the result the SO author posted in his question. It doesn't solve his problem though... Which is the point of posting an answer.

Comment: OP clearly states: *You can review the array I want "result"*. I don't know why you feel that your interpretation of the question supersedes that.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I've updated my answer just to give "that" result... With that said still pointing to the main objective of actually solving their problem. I've included both. Thank you

Comment: It still doesn't produce *"that"* result.

Comment: @SharpDev if you edit your question to make it a runnable stack snippet that logs its output to the console then we don't have to have a dispute about what it does or doesn't do - people can just click the _run code snippet_ button and easily see for themselves what your code outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive solution. The idea is to recursively process the children, and add the processed child array to the output.

```js
const base = [{
  name: "Jonh"
}, {
  name: "jane"
}, {
  name: "Tom",
  children: [{
    name: "Jery"
  }, {
    name: "Mart"
  }, {
    name: "Mary",
    children: [{
      name: "bob"
    }]
  }]
}, {
  name: "boboy"
}];

const fn = (nodes) => {
  const result = [];
  nodes.forEach((node) => {
    result.push(node);
    if (node.children) {
      result.push(fn(node.children));
    }
  });
  return result;
}

const result = fn(base);
console.log(result);
```

---

<sup>**Note:** review the output of the snippet in the browser's console. The snippet editor's output will replace the duplicated nodes with references.</sup>

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: Can I explain why? Why what?

Comment: Oh sorry, I commented in the wrong place

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for answering my question and I have based on your answers and found my solution as follows:

```
const filterChild = (arr) => {
let result = [...arr];
arr.forEach((col) => {
  if (col.children ) {
    result = result.concat([filterChild(col.children )]);
  }
});

return result;
```

};

Comment: Your solution does not meet your own requirements.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: Because the order of elements in the array is different from what you state to be your expected result.